# Converting If-Then-Else statement to If-Then statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Does anyone know how to convert this if-then-else statement to if-then statement? It is so confusing. Where to put the else part and to ensure that the structure is the same with if-then-else statement? Thank you for your help.

```
if ((symptom1.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))) //fever 3 to 14 days
            {
                weight = 0.75; //cf

                if ((symptom2.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))) //rash on any part of the body
                {
                    weight = 0.55; //cf

                    if ((symptom3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))) //muscle pain
                    {
                        weight = 0.45; //cf


                        if ((symptom4.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))) //low blood pressure
                        {
                            weight = 0.38; //cf

                            if ((symptom5.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))) //bleeding gum
                            {
                                weight = 0.48; //cf

                                if ((symptom6.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))) //bloody feces
                                {
                                    weight = 0.35; //cf

                                    //severe
                                    newWeight = 0.7 * 0.35; //cf for disease = 0.7 [min=0.35]

                                    String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, resultSevereDengue.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else //consult doctor
                                {
                                    weight = 0.3; //cf min
                                    newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

                                    String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                            //consultDoctor
                            else
                            {
                                weight = 0.3; //cf min
                                newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

                                String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
                                intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                        //uncomplicated
                        else
                        {
                            newWeight = 0.6 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0.6 [min=0.3]

                            String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, resultUncomplicatedDengue.class);
                            intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                    //consultDoctor
                    else
                    {
                        weight = 0.3; //cf min
                        newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

                        String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
                        intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
                //consultDoctor
                else
                {
                    weight = 0.3; //cf min
                    newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

                    String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
                    intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
            //absent dengue
            else if ((symptom1.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))) //fever 1 to 3 days
            {
                weight = 0.7; //cf

                if ((symptom2.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))) //rash on any part of the body
                {
                    weight = 0.5; //cf

                    if ((symptom3.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))) //muscle pain
                    {
                        weight = 0.4; //cf

                        if ((symptom4.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))) //low blood pressure
                        {
                            weight = 0.3; //cf

                            if ((symptom5.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))) //bleeding gum
                            {
                                weight = 0.4; //cf

                                if ((symptom6.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))) //bloody feces
                                {
                                    weight = 0.35; //cf

                                    //absent
                                    newWeight = 0.8 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0.8 [min=0.3]

                                    String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, resultAbsentDengue.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else //consultDoctor
                                {
                                    weight = 0.3; //cf min
                                    newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

                                    String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                            else //consultDoctor
                            {
                                weight = 0.3; //cf min
                                newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

                                String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
                                intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                        else //consultDoctor
                        {
                            weight = 0.3; //cf min
                            newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

                            String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
                            intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                    else //consultDoctor
                    {
                        weight = 0.3; //cf min
                        newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

                        String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
                        intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
                //consultDoctor
                else
                {
                    weight = 0.3; //cf min
                    newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

                    String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
                    intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried refactoring the code using any IDE? It is pretty straightforward how to shorten this mess to ~20 lines of code.

Comment: Move common code to a helper method. That would be `String cf = ...` to `startActivity(intent);`, passing in `newWeight` and the `.class` to use. Then, unless needed *after* the `if` statement, eliminate `weight` and `newWeight` variables and just specify directly as parameter.

Comment: Why? What's the motivation for this strange request?

Comment: @EJP My guess is because OP realized it's ugly as ****. Definitely not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Very unwieldy.

Comment: it should be easy if I can use the other methods. I want to convert this statement to IF-THEN statement only because to fulfill the rule based technique. If I'm not mistaken, the rule based technique only use IF THEN statement.

Comment: by the way, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should take any decent IDE and do that work by yourself. Here are the hints:

1) Find repetitive blocks of code, e.g.

```
String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
startActivity(intent);
```

and move them to a method like `startCfDiseaseIntent`.

2) Remove your commentaries, and replace them with self-describing code:

```
symptom1.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))) //fever 3 to 14 days
```

Should be extracted to local variable

```
boolean isFeverMoreThanTwoDays = symptom1.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes");
```

And then reused.

You can still leave a commentary, but near that `boolean`.

Moreover you can combine new booleans to create new self-decribing booleans, like:

```
boolean patientHasExtremelyDangerousInfection = isFever... && isMusclePainPresent && isGumBleeding && ...;
```

And then use them to make a decision.

3) Find unnecessary code:

In the second half, where `symptom1.equalsIgnoreCase("No")` all of your else blocks are the same, so you can collapse all the checks to one with `&&`, and remove that whole `if-then-else` tree.

In the first half: my IDE shows that almost all calls to `weight = ...; // cf` are overwritten further without being read in-between, so there are a lot of redundant lines over there - make them useful, or remove.

4) Create a test if necessary. Your code consumes 7 variables that can be either "yes" or "no". That makes 2^7 input variations, which is a small number. You can easily create a program that executes all of these variations, consumes resulting `cf` and puts that data into some file. Afterwards with the help of that file you can assure that your new code actually works according to the old logic.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that the value of symptomN must be "Yes" or "No".

```
static boolean check(String[] symptoms, String... values) {
    if (values.length != symptoms.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < symptoms.length; ++i) {
        if (!symptoms[i].equalsIgnoreCase(values[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and

```
    String[] symptoms = { symptom1, symptom2, symptom3, symptom4, symptom5, symptom6 };

    if (check(symptoms, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")) {
        weight = 0.35; //cf

        //severe
        newWeight = 0.7 * 0.35; //cf for disease = 0.7 [min=0.35]

        String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

        Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, resultSevereDengue.class);
        intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (check(symptoms, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No")) {
        weight = 0.3; //cf min
        newWeight = 0 * 0.3; //cf for disease = 0

        String cf = Double.toString(newWeight);

        Intent intent = new Intent(resultDengue1.this, consultDoctor.class);
        intent.putExtra("cfDisease", cf);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (check(symptoms, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes")) {
        // ...
```